# gtts is not saving on the second generated voice

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_to_python_program", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File "path_to_python_program", line 142, in main
    tts.save("audio_file")
  File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 334, in save
    with open(str(savefile), "wb") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'audio_file'
```

I was expecting for it to work the same as the first one.